# JavaScript application bug: counter variable skips a value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am working on a pure JavaScript infinite scroll. I have a 4 list of posts.

I am trying to load more posts (clones of the "original" ones) when I reach the bottom of the container.

```js
class InfiniteScroll {
  constructor() {
    this.observer = null;
    this.isLoading = false;
    this.postsContainer = document.querySelector('#postsContainer');
    this.postsArary = postsContainer.querySelectorAll('.post');
    this.iterationCount = Number(this.postsContainer.dataset.currentPage);
    this.perPage = 5;
    this.maxCount = this.postsContainer?.dataset?.maxCount;
    this.numberOfPages = Math.ceil(this.maxCount / this.perPage);
    this.hasNextPage = this.iterationCount < this.numberOfPages;
  }

  loadMorePosts() {
    if (this.hasNextPage) {
      this.postsArary.forEach(item => {
        let postClone = item.cloneNode(true);
        this.postsContainer.appendChild(postClone);
      });
    } else {
      if (this.observer) this.observer.disconnect();
    }
  }

  getLastPost() {
    const allPosts = [...this.postsArary];
    return allPosts[allPosts.length - 1];
  }

  counter() {
     console.log(this.iterationCount);
    if (this.hasNextPage) {
      this.iterationCount++;
      this.postsContainer.dataset.currentPage = this.iterationCount;
    }

    this.postsContainer.dataset.hasNextPage = this.hasNextPage;
    this.hasNextPage = this.iterationCount < this.numberOfPages;
  }

  bindLoadMoreObserver() {
    if (this.postsContainer) {
      this.observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
          if (entry && entry.isIntersecting) {
            observer.unobserve(entry.target);
            this.counter();
            this.loadMorePosts();
            observer.observe(this.getLastPost());
          }
        });
      });

      this.observer.observe(this.getLastPost());
    }
  }

  init() {
    this.bindLoadMoreObserver();
  }
}

const infiniteScroll = new InfiniteScroll();
infiniteScroll.init();
```

```css
body, body * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.post {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="postsContainer" data-has-next-page="true" data-current-page="1" data-max-count="11">
  <div class="post">
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque dolorum consequatur nostrum sapiente ipsa! Veniam, laudantium accusantium, odio maxime quo adipisci possimus enim quam, voluptate quidem animi perferendis delectus aliquam?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque dolorum consequatur nostrum sapiente ipsa! Veniam, laudantium accusantium, odio maxime quo adipisci possimus enim quam, voluptate quidem animi perferendis delectus aliquam?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <h2>Title 3</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque dolorum consequatur nostrum sapiente ipsa! Veniam, laudantium accusantium, odio maxime quo adipisci possimus enim quam, voluptate quidem animi perferendis delectus aliquam?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <h2>Title 4</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque dolorum consequatur nostrum sapiente ipsa! Veniam, laudantium accusantium, odio maxime quo adipisci possimus enim quam, voluptate quidem animi perferendis delectus aliquam?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### The problem

There is an issue with the `iterationCount` variable: it does not seem to reach the value 2.

I have not been able to spot the cause of that.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array `postsArary` is initialized in the constructor and never updated: `getLastPost()` always returns the fourth post instead of the last one that was added dynamically. Consequently, the `IntersectionObserver` callback is only triggered by the fourth post and not by the one on the bottom of the page.

The updated `getLastPost()` method:

```
getLastPost() {
  const allPosts = postsContainer.querySelectorAll('.post');
  return allPosts[allPosts.length - 1];
}
```

---

This doesn't completely fix the issue. The third page still won't load because `counter()` is called before `loadMorePosts()`. So for the final page, `hasNextPage` is already `false` when `loadMorePosts()` should still load more posts.

The updated callback:

```
bindLoadMoreObserver() {
    if (this.postsContainer) {
      this.observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
          if (entry && entry.isIntersecting) {
            observer.unobserve(entry.target);
            this.loadMorePosts();
            this.counter();
            if (this.hasNextPage) {
              observer.observe(this.getLastPost());
            }
          }
        });
      });

      this.observer.observe(this.getLastPost());
    }
  }
```

Comment: How would you make it instead?

Comment: I updated my answer with specific changes.